# Dictionary table relationships (MS SQL 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

I have table named **'Dictionary'** with columns as follow:

- ID   bigint
- TYPE varchar (200)
- ITEM varchar (200)

Table is used by various tables as simple dictionary / lookup.
Eg it stores countries, titles, business type lists.

**TYPE** column keeps info about type of dictionary , **ITEM** is dictionary string value.

All works well  but **I have problem to set up relationship between dictionary and foreigin tables.**
When I'm using 'Foreign Key Relationship' I can not make it depended of 'TYPE" column.

*(Please note same item with same type - eg 'countries' can be linked to several tables, when item with another type can be linked to different)*

Currently I'm using USPs to manage that but I'd like to switch to standard relationship mechanism.
Any advice how to get that?

Comment: What Column-types are the described columns?

Comment: types added as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you could consider an alternative design

```
Dictionary table
ID (pk)
DICTIONARY_TYPE_ID (fk to dictionaryType) 
ITEM

DictionaryType table
ID (pk)
DESCRIPTION
```

and then make links to the **ID** of **DictionaryType** table in places where you currently want to reference **Type** field from your original design

Answer (score 0):

From the context of the question, I'm guessing you'll need to do one of two things:

- Make your `Type` column the primary key
- or have the foreign keys depend on the `ID` field here.

Foreign keys need to refer to a primary key, and it looks like your `Type` column isn't a PK.

Comment: Not a good answer I think. Yes, FK's refer to a primary key but that PK us usually found in the table you are referring to (in this case the table 'TYPES' or something with a PK-column 'TypeID')

Comment: You're right if this table isn't the PK end of a relationship (which is what the question reads like; "between dictionary and foreigin tables" suggests the FK is defined on some third table).

Answer (score 0):

what you have here is an EAV db design which is bad for number of reasons one being your problem. there is no solution for this in the real sense. you might try using sql_variant as a column type for the item and try to to a PK-FK relationship on that.

there's another way you could try to do this with the xml datatype and schemas like i describe [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2006/10/14/14032.aspx). however you'll have to test this to see if it applies to your problem.